# Replace placeholder tags in HTML with values from code

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, html-table

I have an HTML table in asp.net with placeholder tags, like #value1# and #value2#.  The tags are currently the text in the `<td>` element.

In C# I would like to replace these text with values that I calculate from code.
What is the best method to replace the HTML tags from C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the placeholders `Literal` controls and output the value to the `Text` property:

```
<asp:Literal runat="server" ID="PlaceHolder1" />

PlaceHolder1.Text = "content that would replace placeholder text";
```